# Python 3, capturing key combinations

Tags: python, keypress

I am writing long running program with simple GUI, the 99% of time I would like the program to work only as process, however sometimes I want to check the status, so is it possible to capture the keypress event in python?
For example I want to show the program window when I press Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Q, I expect to use app on Windows
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are tutorials on how to create a key-logger with Python. They should help. But I do not know if that is the right way to go. 
Also you could register shortcuts under a key combination on Windows.

You should be aware that `Ctrl+Shift+Alt` are handled independent of the keyboard layout and `Q` changes with the language.

With pywin32 you should be able to do that using `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+F1` for example.